# How to extract random substrings from a string in php?

Tags: php, keyword

I would like to extract random substrings form a string, how could I do this?

Lets say I have this text

`$text = "Some totally random text I have, and I want to work on it! But need 
           some php skillz...";`

and as a result I want an array like this with extracted substrings

```
$random_string[0] = "random text I have";

$random_string[1] = "I have, and I want to work";

$random_string[2] = "need some php skillz...";
```

Comment: You mean you dont have any conditions on when or how a sub-string must be made??

Comment: Thanks for the comment, one condition is to cut off at white space, so the script wont cut words in their middle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$words = explode(' ', $string);
$numWords = count($words);
echo join(' ', array_slice($words, mt_rand(0, $numWords - 1), mt_rand(1, $numWords)));
```

Answer (score 3):

Create **two random numbers** which is less than the length of the string

```
$n1=rand(1, strlen($string));
$n2=rand(1, strlen($string));
```

Then create a sub string using `$n`

```
$new_string = substr($string, $n1, $n2)
```

Hope this helps

---

**Updated:**

You can do like this to get words ,

```
$string = "Hello Stack over Flow in here ";
```

The use `explode` - Returns an array of strings, each of which is a substring of string

```
$pieces = explode(" ", $string);
```

**$pieces** will be a array of sepearte words of your string

**Example :**

```
$pieces[0] = "Hello"
$pieces[1] = "can"
```

Then use `array_rand` — Pick one or more random entries out of an array

```
$rand_words = array_rand($pieces, 2);
```

so `$rand_words` will have two random words from your string

**Example :**

```
$rand_words[0]= "Stack"
$rand_words[1]= "Over"
```

Comment: Appreciated Sudantha, how could I modify this to cutoff only at whitespace?

Comment: @giorgio79 - can u post a example here?

Comment: Sure, so if we have this
`$text = "Some totally random text I have, and I want to work on it! But need some php skillz...";`
I think your solution would extract sg like this as well 
`"ally rand"`
however I want cutoffs to always be at whitespace, so it should be
`"totally random"`

Comment: ill check on this giime few mins

Answer (score 0):

Use [substr](http://php.net/substr) with random start and lengths.

```
$random_string = substr($text, rand(1, mb_strlen($text) - 20), rand(10, 20));
```

Adjust your values and add more logic if you need.

Comment: Appreciated Blair, how could I modify this to cutoff only at whitespace?

Comment: this is not 100% correct what happen if the random number is > length of the string ? it will always gives the full string

Comment: I know, I didn't have the time to write a full example, that's why I had the final line of text there. deceze has the better method anyway.